# Declaring variables in external files?

Tags: javascript, external, src

External javascript (eg. ***src="MyJavascript.js"***) loads but doesn't execute (expected).

But my (numerous) external javascript files have variable declarations scattered throughout that fail to get defined since the script didn't run.

I solved the problem by changing the script ***src="MyJavascript.js"***
TO
***document.write(src="MyJavascript.js);***
that works fine, it loads the script and executes it as intended BUT THERE MUST BE A BETTER WAY?

Comment: Please post the complete line of the `src` part

Comment: Please provide some code to demonstrate the failure.

Comment: Are you exporting the required variables from you MyJavascript.js file? If there is a function (you mentioned word execute), then how are you executing the function. If you want it to be immediately executed on file load, then did you try IIFE <https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE>

Comment: Complete line:<script src="MyJavascript.js"></script>;

Comment: Some global variables are declared and initialized in the various javascript files that I have saved externally from the HTML pages but the initialization doesn't work since they are not executed.  If I include them with document.write it works fine but I hate using document.write like that.